# On the "Check for running processes" activity, the "Include launchers" option does nothing

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j Windows Edition 6.1.1 (build 6254).

I have an installer that installs (up to) 3 components, each with a Launcher (exe).

In the uninstall process, I use a "Check for running processes" activity, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476403/how-do-i-check-if-the-installed-program-is-running-at-the-beginning-of-the-insta). The "Include launchers" option is checked, but no processes are detected.

When I add the exe files manually to "Additional executables", it works as expected.

Is this a bug, or did I miss something?

Additional question: When I list the "Additional executables", can I give them names by which they are reported to the user when they are running, rather than just filename with path?

In case it matters: The components are Eclipse RCP application, and they are not placed in the installation root, but each in its own subdirectory.

Comment: Does this also happen with the most recent version?

Comment: Yes, I just reproduced this behaviour with this version: install4j Windows Edition 7.0.9 (build 7273).

Comment: Is this a generated launcher or an external launcher?

Comment: It is an external launcher. The exe is created during the Maven build, before install4j is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 7.0.9, the "Include launchers" option of the "Check for processes" action only handles generated launchers and you have to pass the external launchers explicitly in the "Additional executables" property.

Comment: I accepted the answer, since it gives me useful information and I can move on. However, this does not explain the behaviour as observed with version 6.1.1. Also, it would be nice if the GUI could mention this limitation.